# How do you implement the background worker with Pebble.js?

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble, pebble-js

I want my Pebble.js to run in the background, mainly using the Pebble's accelerometer. I was wondering how people did this, since most of the pebble docs are in C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot run a Pebble.js app in the background.

Since Pebble.js is actually running on the phone, not on the watch, it must maintain a connection between the app on the watch and your phone in order to do anything. You cannot communicate between a background worker the phone, so you would not be able to maintain the connection.

There aren't any Pebble.js APIs for the background worker, and that's why.

Theoretically, some sort of background worker support could be added to Pebble.js, where you could launch a predefined worker from Pebble.js, but it would be very limited.